# How to fix "No such file or directory" error message on terminal wget download

Tags: terminal

I am installing files with `wget` onto an external hard drive. Someone walked by, tripped, and disconnected my hard drive briefly. However, now my file download says: "no such file or directory" for each file, and then continues. I have paused the process, exited and re-entered the directory, but I've had no luck. Is there a way to restart the download without getting an error message

Comment: Can you show an example of the wget you are runnIng? Are you downloading to the current directory in Terminal or to a different one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a hard disk is disconnected while it is being written to, you need to do a few things before you can use it again. This also depends on which format was used on the hard disk.

- Connect the hard disk
- Start the Disk Utility
- Find the external hard disk on the left hand side of the disk utility and right-click (or control-click) on it
- Select 'Run First Aid', then when it asks you if you want to run First Aid, click 'Run'
- Allow the process to run to completion.
- After it has finished, if there were no errors on the disk, everything is fine. You can then continue. If there are errors on the disk, then you probably need to delete the file you were trying to download and start the download again.

If there were no errors, you can continue an interrupted download in wget by using the -c flag, for example:

```
wget -c https://example.com/file.ext
```

Best of luck! And keep your cables out of the way of anyone who might be walking past :)

Comment: The first aid says everything is fine but terminal says: "failed host is down" when I try to continue

Comment: That means it can't connect to the URL you are trying to download from. Please check your network connection

Comment: My network connection also seems to be fine. I created another script to download from the site onto my computer and it worked

Comment: "Host is down" is a network error

Comment: It also has the same error message "no such file or directory"

Comment: What is the full command-line you are typing? It is difficult to guess otherwise, where the problem may be coming from. "No such file or directory" is usually a local (not network) error